# Adding an `if` statement to send an Email when the count of Likes reaches a certain No

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add an IF statement so that when the Like Count reaches 2 an email is sent. I have written the codes but it is not working, I am trying with the below but it is not working.

My question is how to add an if statement so that when any item with likes more the 2 an email is sent a specific email.

Here is the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='liked', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

Here is the views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(
            post=post, reply=None).order_by('-id')
        total_likes = post.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST or None)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                content = self.request.POST.get('content')
                reply_id = self.request.POST.get('comment_id')
                comment_qs = None

                if reply_id:
                    comment_qs = Comment.objects.get(id=reply_id)
                comment = Comment.objects.create(
                    post=post, user=self.request.user, content=content, reply=comment_qs)
                comment.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("post_detail.html")
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        context["comments"] = comments
        context["comment_form"] = comment_form
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        res = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.object.incrementViewCount()
        return res


def LikeView(request):
    # post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True

    context = {
        'total_likes': post.total_likes,
        'liked': liked,
        'post': post
    }

    if post.likes.count() == 2:
        msg = EmailMessage('Count Reached',
                           settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [request.user.email])
        msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
        msg.fail_silently = False
        msg.send()

    if request.is_ajax:
        html = render_to_string('like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

Comment: what did you try and where did you fail

Comment: @iklinac updated question with trial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this this happen everywhere, I would recommend adding an override to the `save()` method of the `Post` model, and send the email there when it increases to two likes. You can also use Django's `send_mail` function, which is a nice wrapper for sending email. Fat models, skinny views, dumb templates is a mantra for best Django practices. Maybe something like this:

```py
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='liked', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        if self.total_likes() == 2:
            send_mail(
                "my subject",
                "my text message",
                "myemail@myhost.com",
                ["myuser@theirhost.com"],
                html_message="<h1>My HTML Message</h1>",
            )
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) 

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

Good luck!

Comment: shouldn't it be **`if self.total_likes()`** instead of `if self.likes` ?

Comment: Yes, you're right! However, I'd recommend creating a `total_likes` `models.IntegerField` on the `Post` model and incrementing by one each time you add a related row to `likes`. This will be a much lower query cost to look up in the long run for a trivial amount of space per post.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. There are chances where we could forget to update the count while adding or removing the items from an M2M relation.

Comment: Either way. Just be aware, once you have lots of rows in the relational table, you will see significant slow downs. But that can be addressed down the road. Cheers.